# Dart/Flutter : http error : XMLHttpRequest

Tags: flutter

Im trying to get   places id from google api,

it's a search field

i followed a video and i put the key and the key is working fine
but now im getting this error

error :

```
      Error: XMLHttpRequest error. 
        C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 963:28                get current
    packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22                                                                                    <fn>
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1685:54                                              runUnary
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 557:7                                         [_complete]
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1530:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37309:58                              <fn>
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:57717/dart_sdk.js:5093:12)
    at Error._throw (http://localhost:57717/dart_sdk.js:20399:18)
    at Error.throwWithStackTrace (http://localhost:57717/dart_sdk.js:20396:18)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:57717/dart_sdk.js:40921:18)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:57717/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:57717/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:57717/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

the api config :

```
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class LocationService {
  final String key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  Future<String> getPlaceId(String input) async {
    final String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=$input&inputtype=textquery&key=$key';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

    var placeId = json['candidates'][0]['place_id'] as String;

    print(placeId);

    return placeId;
  }
  // Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getPlace(String input) async {}
}
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, try adding the string input inside your URL and also the key inside the URL.

Compare with this code:

```dart
final String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Museum%20of%20Contemporary%20Art%20Australia&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address%2Cname%2Crating%2Copening_hours%2Cgeometry&key=YOUR_API_KEY'
```

Also try enabling billing in your google cloud console.

Comment: i tried that, and still get the same error. i already enabled my google cloud console